# Class not found Exception in RConsole

Tags: r, rjava

I have a es.r script which is written in rJava.So My R script internally calls my Java functions . I created a batch file for setting the classPath with all the dependencies .
I am able to run the script in terminal using Rscript.But when I try to run the script from RConsole using source() I am getting Class Not Found Exception .

Any Idea ?

## EDIT

Included

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(rJava)
#.jclassPath()
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath(dir("E:\\Documents and Settings\\Admin\\My Documents\\Downloads\\OG-R\\target\\mavenLib", full.names=TRUE ))

.jclassPath()
```

got

> Error in .jcall(obj, "[[Ljava/lang/String;",
> "getAllContentFromKeyword",  :  java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message said that it can't find the class path ,probably because you 
specified an aboslute path.

maybe you can try this :

```
library(rJava) 
.jinit() 
.jaddClassPath(yourclassPath)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply  Agstudy.I was  not added .jaddClassPath() I tried adding then gettin Null pointer Exception on .jcall() .I have edited my post .Please reviiew

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you :(  E:\\Documents and Settings\\Admin\\My Documents\\Downloads\\OG-R\\target\\mavenLib   contains all of my .jar files that is necessary to run my progaram and I can run it from terminal

Comment: try to add all them for example!

Comment: I tried adding .jaddClassPath("E:\\Documents and Settings\\Admin\\My Documents\\Downloads\\OG-R\\target\\mavenLib\\ClientPortfolioCreator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar") like this added all jars in my es.r .But getting the same Null piinter exception . getting Exception in line .jcall()

Comment: Finally I got the root cause of my problem .I had one configuration file and while running with RConsole need to change the working directory using setwd("path") .Thanks agstudy for your all support

Comment: @user1790894:) you are welcom!